# Read output from PsExec

Tags: c#, .net, c#-4.0, psexec

hi iam trying to execute a ipconfig on my remote machine using PsExec tool but i am get the Psexec tool exits with error code 0

here the code which i used

```
Process p = new Process();
p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardError = true;
p.StartInfo.Domain = txtDomainName.Text;
p.StartInfo.UserName = txtUser.Text;
p.StartInfo.Password = secure;
p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardInput = true;
p.StartInfo.FileName = AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory + @"PSTools\psexec.exe";
p.StartInfo.Arguments = String.Format(@"\\{0}  /accepteula cmd.exe ipconfig /all > c:\output.log", ipAddress);
p.Start();
p.WaitForExit();
string output = string.Empty;
while (!p.StandardError.EndOfStream)
{
   output += p.StandardError.ReadToEnd().ToString();
}
```

How can we read the output using psexec tool what mistake am i doing

Comment: You can get the same data with WMI, you don't need to run an external program

Comment: actually what i wan to do is run my application which will check the out dataprocess is reacheable or not on remote machine for sample now iam getting the ipconfig if it works fine then i will my application using psexec tool

Comment: You can do that using the classes in the same namespace as WMI, System.Automation. You can create a Powershell pipeline and specify that it should execute on a remote computer

Comment: can  you give some example..

Answer (score 0):

It's quite difficult to retrieve the output code, it seems it's not included into the Error Code.
I had the same issue, but i've decided to go for a workaround
A solution would be to write the result into temp txt file, read it from there, delete the file.

Regards,

Alex